JMeter-Unable to pass extracted value from one request into subsequent request as the value is showing up in response but not in the request
I'm working on some REFRESH tab , where my screen shows up updated time post hitting refersh button of one particular image.
So handle this in JMeter , I have extracted value of this date timestamp from one request and trying to pass into REQUEST of subsequent actual request(because in this, I see updated refresh date in timestamp response).
Kindly suggest how to handle this from JMeter tool.
I tried extracting value of the timestamp from previous request but unable to replace it in next subsequent request but there is some timestamp related data in response of this request.
My request doesn't have any Timestamp in  Headers , to pass or replace the extracted value.

I think the "timestamp" is generated by client-side JavaScript. As per JMeter project main page:

JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so if you need to generate current timestamp you will need to do it yourself, JMeter provides __time() function which can produce current date and time in various formats:

More information on JMeter Functions concept: Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction
